# KeywordFilter field to filter from database values

Tags: sql, sqlite, blackberry, java-me

How can i implement a KeywordFilter field to filter data from the database table as soon as text is fed into the field.

Most of the samples I have come across demonstrates filtering from predefined arrays.What i am looking out for is filtering from database.

Please guide how to go about it.Thanks

I have tried out this [example of BB docs which shows in arrays](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Search_field_1214696_11.jsp)

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward approach would be to load the data from the database into a [ReadableList](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/collection/ReadableList.html) and pass that to the [KeywordFilterField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/KeywordFilterField.html).

The method used to set the values is
`setSourceList(ReadableList list, KeywordProvider helper)`

ReadableList is an interface which has a few implementations.  The example code you are looking at uses the [SortedReadableList](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/collection/util/SortedReadableList.html) but a [BasicFilteredList](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/collection/util/BasicFilteredList.html) would work nicely too.